# How to keep listview from pushing text down?

Tags: android, listview, android-relativelayout

With a TextView on Top, a ListView second, The a TextView on bottom, how do I keep the last TextView pinned to the bottom of the screen, the ListView to fill between the top textView and bottom TextView, and never have the list push the last TextView off screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I do.  (Following this example, of course you'd replace the ScrollView with your ListView.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="My Header Text" />
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all.  Lots of content that needs to be scrolled, to see it all." />
    </ScrollView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="My Footer Text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And here's what it looks like on my G2.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Nest a linear layout to hold the listview.

Answer (score 1):

you need `android:layout_weight="1"` in the ListView and `android:layout_weight="0"` in the bottom TextView. I do a similar thing to your wanting and that works

Edit: actually You might need to put a nested `LinearLayout android:layout_weight="0"` around the bottom TextView. I have a bottom bar which is enclosed in a LL but you might be able to use the layout_weight directly on your TextView

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two ways.
First,

Take the TextView out of LinearLayout, then combine the LinearLayout and the TextView inside a RelativeLayout. Add  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" to the TextView.

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
        <!-- All your other elements in here -->
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Second, taking the entire relative layout to the bottom (as i am using)

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <Button
        android:text="@string/label_submit_button"
        android:id="@+id/Button"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Button"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```